# Proof that $2^n-1$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ even

Tags: solution-verification, induction

**Basis**: This is true for $ n = 2 $
$$ 2^2 - 1 = 3 $$

**Hypothesis**: There exists a number $ k $ that satisfies the expression $ 2^k -1 = 3a $.

**Induction step**: If $ k $ is even so the next valid number is $ k + 2 $:
$$ 2^k - 1 = 2^{k+2} - 4 = 2^{k+2}-1 = 3\cdot a \cdot 4 + 3 = 3b $$

I think that is is the proof but I don't know if is right or fully complete.

Comment: If you let $k=1$ then your induction equation becomes $2-1=8-4=8-1$, so it is clearly not correct.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales it holds only when $k$ is even

Comment: When $k=2$ the equation becomes $4-1=16-4=16-1$, that is, it claims that $3=12=15$. Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clearly in step induction, I tried says that $(2^k -1) \cdot 2^2 = 2^{k+2} - 4$ and so on. But see that I fail dramatic

Comment: I made the steps in answer @P.J. but tried puts all together in one line and I  messed up everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction step: Suppose given statement holds for $k$, an even number. To show: the given statement holds for $k+2$.

$$\begin{align}2^{k+2} - 1 &= 4\cdot2^k - 1\\&=3\cdot2^k + (2^k - 1)\\ &=3\cdot2^k + 3a \textrm{, since } 3|(2^k-1) \\&=3\cdot(2^k +a) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your induction step is somehow unclear.$$2^{k+2}-1=2^2{2^k}-1=\\4\times 2^k-1\\=3\times 2^k+2^k-1\\=\underbrace{3\times 2^k}_{3a}+\underbrace{2^k-1}_{3b}$$